# Write large file in Python with problems

Tags: python

I am dealing with ConceptNet Json files, and trying to extract relationships between entities in the files. The file is very large, for example, `part_00.json` is `1.4Gb`, I write a Python program to handle the large file and try to save the processed data into a new output file. The source code is provided below:

```
import json

inputData = "d:\\part_00.jsons"
outputData = "d:\\output.jsons"
fin = open(inputData, 'r')  
fout = open(outputData, 'w')

outputfile =[]
for eachLine in fin:  
    line = eachLine.strip()
    line = line.strip(',')                                   
    js = None  
    try:  
        js = json.loads(line)  
        outputfile.append(js["uri"])   
    except Exception,e:  
        print 'bad line'  
        continue

for line in outputfile:
    if line.startswith("/a"):
        a = line[4:-1]
        r, c1, c2 = a.split(",")
        if c1.split("/")[2] == "en" and c2.split("/")[2] == "en":
            fout.write((" ".join((r, c1.split("/")[3], c2.split("/")[3]))).encode('utf8'))
            fout.write("\n")    

fout.close()
```

However, when I run the program, I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workspace\CSK\src\readJson.py", line 48, in <module>
    r, c1, c2 = a.split(",")
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Then I checked the output file `output.jsons` and found that it has only `57mb` size and incomplete.

I do not know what is the cause of the problem. Is it due to the large size of the file? Or there are some cache error? I wish to have your answers.

Comment: By the way, when I test the program on a small size of file, it works

Comment: The error is not associated with the size of the data you are trying to work with. Rather, I think one of your lines of data does not contain exactly three values, thus `r, c1, c2 = a.split(",")` is failing. The small file working is  probably coincidental - it happens not to contain the line of data that causes the error.

Comment: You can see what line the problem is on by catching it in a try statement like this: `try: r, c1, c2 = a.split(",")     except ValueError: print a`. It'll come up with an error straight after unless you edit other bits of the code, but it'll let you know which line is the culprit.

Comment: As mentioned many times in the documentation, it's highly recommended to use Context Manager to open files. Use the `with` statement, especially for big files.